# String methods in Swift to replace the first character in a string

Tags: ios, string, swift

Say I have a string that contains three underscores

```
var myString = "___"
```

Given a number, the string should look like this

```
myString = "1__"
```

If the user types a new number, say 2, the string will change

```
myString = "12_"
```

Given a `number`, I tried coding this situation:

```
for i in myString.characters {
    if (i == "_") {
        newString = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("_", withString: number, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
        break
    }
}
```

The problem is that `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` replaces the characters all at once. What string method do you think I should use instead?

Comment: Where are you getting the values from in the first place? A single text field in which the user is typing?

Comment: @KennethBruno I'm getting the values from a handwriting recognition SDK, not exactly a text field - sorry. I wanted to make things sound as simple as possible.

Comment: Ok so you have values come in 1 by 1. Why not store them in an array and build the string from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the user input string and pad it with '_':

```
var userInput = "1" // This is the string from the text field input by the user

var finalText = userInput.stringByPaddingToLength(3, withString: "_", startingAtIndex: 0)
```

Comment: Nice. Best solution until now. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally vote for [@giorashc:s <strike>native</strike> padding solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36383770/4573247) (*), but to additionally add to the variety of answers this question (as this Q&A already contains a few variations), you could also make use of the `suffixFrom(...)` method for the `CharacterView` of your template string (`___`) to achieve the padding behaviour. E.g.:

```
/* Example (if length of string >= template: just return string) */
let padToTemplate: (str: String, withTemplate: String) -> String = {
    return $0.characters.count < $1.characters.count
        ? $0 + String($1.characters.suffixFrom($0.characters.endIndex))
        : $0
}

/* Example usage */
let myString = padToTemplate(str: "1", withTemplate: "___")
print(myString) // 1__
```

---

*(*) Thanks @KennethBruno for pointing out that `.stringByPaddingToLength(..)` is from `NSString` and not native Swift!*

Comment: How is his solution native? It uses the bridge from Swift's `String` to Cocoa's `NSString`. Not that there's anything wrong with that, use whatever works, but native usually means Swift-only. Also, why use a closure instead of a function? You're basically mimicking a function with a immutable variable and a closure. Wouldn't it be more clear to use the function syntax?

Comment: @KennethBruno Thanks for the feedback! I didn't realize `.stringByPaddingToLength(..)` was from `NSString` (never seen it before so just figured I'd missed a Swift `String` native method). As for closures vs. functions; I'd say that is a question of preference (in a semi-functional language such as Swift, functions are just a special case of closures). I sometimes tend to use closures in answers as it gives me little additional practice on something I'm not as well-versed at as writing as functions/methods (or the _special case_ closures ;) ).

Comment: I find it best to test examples without any `import` statements to be sure. There's no doubt that a closure as you have here works just fine in place of a function, it's just a bit less clear to the casual reader. Now if it was mutable then you could replace the closure at will, a very interesting method of dynamically changing a "function".

Answer (score 2):

you can use `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` instead after specifying the range you want to replace as the following

```
    let range = myString.rangeOfString("_")
    if range != nil {
        myString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString:number)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use simple search and replace:

```
var template = "_____"

func replace(template: String, _ character: String) -> String {
    var newString = template

    if let index = template.rangeOfString("_") {
        newString.replaceRange(index, with: character)
    }

    return newString
}

template = replace(template, "1")
print(template)

template = replace(template, "2")
print(template)
```

Note that there are far better solution. Personally, I would keep the values as an array and I would build the string dynamically only when needed because it's much easier to work with an array of characters.

Answer (score 1):

i'm sure there are more elegant solutions but maybe it helps:

```
var myString = "___"

myString = "1__"

let input = "6"

for index in 0 ..< myString.characters.count {
    let startIndex = myString.startIndex.advancedBy(index)
    let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(1)
    let range = startIndex..<endIndex
    let substring = myString[range]
    if substring == "_" {
        myString = myString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: input)
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one way of doing it, using a computed property and plain Swift with no NSString methods.

```
class Display {
  var accumulated = [String]()
  var display:String {
    return (accumulated.prefix(3) + ["_","_","_"])
      .prefix(3).joinWithSeparator("")
  }

  func addNumber(number:Int) {
    accumulated.append(String(number))
  }
}

let first = Display()
print(first.display)  // => "___"
first.addNumber(1)
print(first.display)  // => "1__"
first.addNumber(2)
print(first.display)  // => "12_"
first.addNumber(3)
print(first.display)  // => "123"
first.addNumber(4)
print(first.display)  // => "123"
```

Answer (score 1):

'pure' swift solution (no Foundation required)

```
var myString = "___"
let input = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

var arr = myString.characters.map { String($0) }
var idx = 0

input.forEach { (i) in
    if idx < myString.characters.count {
        arr.insert(i, atIndex: arr.startIndex.advancedBy(idx))
        idx += 1
        arr.removeLast()
        myString = arr.joinWithSeparator("")

        print(myString)

    }
}

/*
 1__
 12_
 123
 */
```

Answer (score -1):

At first sight of your issue, you should use the range option/argument something like:

```
if let range =  myString.rangeOfString("_") {
    myString = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("_", withString: number, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: range)
}
```